# Firebase disconnects on cordova pause

Tags: javascript, cordova, firebase

A pretty major problem for my app is that roughly 50% of launches have no Firebase connection unless the app is paused.  So I would:

1. Launch the app to have no data loaded
2. Pause it to load the data on the current page
3. Resume it to see the data.
4. Repeat step 2 and 3 each time I need data sent or received

code:

```
  var onPause = function(){console.log("paused");}
  var onResume = function(){console.log("resumed");}
  document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
  document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);

  var connectionRef = new Firebase(FB + "/.info/connected");
  connectionRef.on("value", function(snap){
    if(snap.val() == true){
      console.log("connected       -------[]------");
    } else {
      console.log("not connected   --------[            ]------------");
    }
  });
```

logs:

```
resumed
not connected   --------[            ]------------
paused
connected       -------[]------
resumed
not connected   --------[            ]------------
paused
connected       -------[]------
```

The reason it works half the time is because it also works the opposite way, which I assume is the intended way.  Is there any way to prevent it from disconnected at all? or alternatively force it to connect on resume?

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause to the problem - It was a plugin called phonegap-plugin-push. When it registers for GCM it causes Firebase to go offline (or online if paused).

I still haven't found a genuine solution, but as a hack fix I have a timer on registering for GCM so the data can load initially before the disconnecting happens.  After that it relies on the user not using the app for extended periods of time so it can pause to sync up on a regular basis.